# Create table in SQL Server as not logged

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transactions

It is possible to create a table in SQL Server as not logged? I just need to create a table with lots of data from lots of tables just to generate reports. In this case the transaction log is not really necessary.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to insert or create without logging at all.

You can probably use `SELECT INTO` to minimize logging. Also try setting the recovery model to `simple or bulk logged`

But you cannot stop SQL Server to create a log file.

You can try this command to set the recovery model to SIMPLE so that to prevent transaction log bloating

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDataBase SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;
```

Comment: What is written to the log when I use a SELECT INTO instruction? It will not write all the inserts in the log like the INSERT INTO instruction?

Comment: I didnt said that if you use SELECT INTO then it will not write to the log. I said if you use SELECT INTO then that will help you to reduce or minimize the log file size. Hope that makes sense!!! :)